# How to select text from that html code?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have some html code

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
     <th class="first">&nbsp;</th>
         <td class="first-col">14</td>
         <td class="">15</td>
         <td class="">16</td>
         <td class="">17</td>
         <td class="">18</td>
         <td class="">19</td>
         <td class="">20</td>
         <td class="last-col">21</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

and i need to select text from first `<td>` (14). I use 
HtmlAgilityPack and code like that:

```
_footer = _htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tfoot/tr/th[@class='first']/td[1]");

return _footer.First().InnerText;
```

It return me nothing. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`td` is not child element of `th`. They are at same level. You should select `td` as direct child of `tr`. And you can specify it's class `first-col` instead of using index:

```
//tfoot/tr/td[@class='first-col']
```

Also don't use `First()` thus you are selecting single node:

```
return _footer.InnerText;
```

NOTE: As Jon pointed, you can still use your code to select cell by index instead of using it's class:

```
//tfoot/tr/td[0]
```

Comment: `//tfoot/tr/td[1]` should also work, if the user wishes to select the first TD, not the specific class (which is more likely to change). Perhaps worth adding both to the answer, and the asker can then take their pick

Comment: @JonStory yes, thats why I pointed this selector as optional one :) But according to markup it seems logical to me. Thanks anyway, I'll add both options